# Selenium scrapy python : No data in csv/jsob

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap information from http://www.qchp.org.qa/en/Pages/searchpractitioners.aspx. I want to do the following:

- Select "Dentist" from the dropdown on the top of the page
- Click search
- Notice that information at the bottom of the page changes dynamically using javascript
- Click on hyperlinks of practitioner names and a popup shows up
- I want to save all that information in a json/csv file for each practitioner.

I also want the information on other pages that are linked at the bottom of the page that changes the information in the save div.

I tried export the data to a json file but it generate an empty file. I don't see any errors in the console.

spider.py

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapytutorial.items import SchItem
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "sch"

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.qchp.org.qa/en/Pages/searchpractitioners.aspx")

    dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$m$g_28bc0e11_4b8f_421f_84b7_d671de504bc3$ctl00$drp_practitionerType")
    all_options = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

    for option in all_options:
        if option.get_attribute("value") == "4":  #Dentist
            option.click()
            break

    driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$m$g_28bc0e11_4b8f_421f_84b7_d671de504bc3$ctl00$Searchbtn").click()


    def parse(self, response):

        all_docs = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        for name in all_docs:
            name.click()
            alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
            sel = Selector(response)
            ma = sel.xpath('//table')
            items = []
            for site in ma:
                item = SchItem()
                item['name'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_Name']/text()").extract()
                item['profession'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_Profession']/text()").extract()
                item['scope_of_practise'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_sop']/text()").extract()
                item['instituition'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_institution']/text()").extract()
                item['license'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_LicenceNo']/text()").extract()
                item['license_expiry_date'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_LicenceExpiry']/text()").extract()
                item['qualification'] = site.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_lbl_Qualification']/text()").extract()

                items.append(item)
            return items
```

Here is items.py
from scrapy.item import Item

```
class SchItem(Item):

    name = Field()
    profession = Field()
    scope_of_practise = Field()
    instituition = Field()
    license = Field()
    license_expiry_date = Field()
    qualification = Field()
```

Comment: Looks like you are not showing the complete code you are using. This `parse()` method is probably a part of a scrapy spider.

Comment: This is the complete code. I'm not using scrapy.. Shall i be using scrapy?

Comment: Nope, scrapy is not required here but could be used for further data processing though. Then, if you are not using `Scrapy` - the `parse()` method is not relevant here. Consider removing it from the question for clearness. Thanks.

Comment: I've added scrapy now. I'm not getting any data in the json file, neither I'm getting any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible ideas:
* indentation of 'return items' - move by 4 units to the left;
** instead of `sel = Selector(response)` try sel = Selector(response.url) -> you're not working with scrapy response, rather with selenium response.